How can there be Christianities?
I'm just curious how there can be more than one truth at the same time? God came to establish a church. Not any church. The church of the first thousand years is the Eastern Orthodox church.

Christians ask many questions that the Bible doesn't have a clear answer for. We can study the scriptures and find an answer that we think is the most likely, but that doesn't mean we're right. If we're honest with our conclusions we we'll distinguish between the things we are certain about and our best attempts at interpreting the unclear.

There can only be one Truth. Indeed. As your avatar says, 'Truth is a Person'. Jesus Christ is the way, the truth and the life. And he said 'I will build my Church'.

Jesus saith unto him, I am the way, the truth, and the life: no man cometh unto the Father, but by me. [John 14:6 KJV]


And I say also unto thee, That thou art Peter, and upon this rock I will build my church; and the gates of hell shall not prevail against it. [Matthe 16:18 KJV]

But we see that, on earth, many claim to be his Church.
Yet, with detailed examination of scripture, many can be seen to err. Then are these all errant churches ? Or are they all apostate churches ?

Remember therefore from whence thou art fallen, and repent, and do the first works; or else I will come unto thee quickly, and will remove thy candlestick out of his place, except thou repent.  [Revelation 2:5 KJV]

Is there any 'church', extant today, that is genuinely His ? Despite that it may err in some ways ?
These are important questions. And we must spend a good portion of our lives seeking, searching, enquiring to find out the answers.

Strive to enter in at the strait gate: for many, I say unto you, will seek to enter in, and shall not be able [Luke 13:24 KJV]

One thing is certain - that Jesus Christ has not failed to do as he said he would - 'I will build my Church'.
Even if 'churches' have all failed - every single one - he will not fail to build again, in a new generation.
Of that, we can be assured.

@Lesley I actually agree with the Community comment. I was remiss in quoting scripture in my answer but not referencing the quotations specifically and citing the instances. It is something I shall have to better consider for the future. The point is ver much taken.

To answer this question, it is useless to consider what the church has become, in its myriad professed identities. It is essential to go back to the beginning, to grasp what Christ said his church was, and what the Apostles knew it to be in their day. Whatever has happened since, what it was then is what it should be now – the original. The inception was the work of Jesus Christ and he promised that he would build it, so that “the gates of Hades shall not prevail against it.” Mat. 16:18.
Two sources of information about its inception remain to us. The first is the meaning of the word we translate as ‘church’ – what did the koine Greek of the New Testament mean by ekklesia? The second source is the sum of knowledge gleaned from the use of that Greek word in the whole New Testament.
The English word 'church', together with the Scottish word 'kirk', the German 'kirche', the Dutch 'kerk', the Swedish 'kyrka', the Russian 'tserkov', the Finnish 'kirkko': all these neither transliterate nor translate anything at all from the New Testament. Ekklesia is a compound word rooted in the simple verb kaleo, 'to call'. To this is joined the preposition ek, 'out of', to create the compound which literally means, 'That which is called out'.
In Matthew 18:17, that which Christ had called out of the world to be his spiritual body could be visibly seen via Christian people, gathered together in worship and in spreading the good news of Christ. Such ‘called out ones’ have always formed the body of Christ throughout the centuries, down to this day. But instead of Christians thinking in terms of their having been called out by Christ, they think in terms of “their church” which is identified by a name that distinguishes it from all the other named denominations. The word ‘church’ has long since come to mean various religious buildings belonging to a particular, organised system, frequently endorsed by the State. Nowhere in the New Testament can that be seen in Christ’s gathered ones.
The biblical word ecclesia is rooted in the Greek kaleo – that which is called out. The calling is not man’s calling upon God, but God’s calling to those he chooses, as in Romans 9:11 & 8:28 & Galatians 1:15 & 1 Corinthians 1:& & 24, Romans 9:11 & 24 etc.
Jesus said that he calls his own sheep by name, and leads them out (John 10:3), and they know his voice and follow him. All such are part of the ekklesia he builds, which the gates of Hades cannot overcome. But how many people who “go to church” to take part in services of worship understand that? All first century Christians understood! They had no buildings specially built for a few gatherings each week. The synagogues soon became closed to them, and the Temple in Jerusalem was soon destroyed.

“Nevertheless, the foundation of God standeth sure, having this seal:
The Lord knoweth those that are his. And, Let every one that nameth
the name of Christ depart from iniquity.” 2 Timothy 2:19 K.J.V.

To specifically deal with the question, then, the first thousand years of Christianity needed no labels to identify it, such as The Eastern Orthodox Church, or The Catholic Church, or any other such name. It was comprised of all those people whom God had called out of the world, sealed and brought into his Kingdom, who named Jesus Christ as their only Lord and Saviour, a genuine naming if they departed from iniquity. Exactly the same means of identification obtains today.
[Some points gleaned from the 363 book The Church - What is it?, John Metcalfe, 1990, http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm ]

I don't want to repeat what has already been said in other answers, but offer one framework of processing through multiple Christian theologies and multiple Christian churches.

How can there be Christianities?  How can there be more than one truth at the same time?
We should distinguish between these 4 concepts in relation to Truth:

God who IS Truth, the Truthmaker, the standard to which all acts of understanding should be measured against.
Jesus Christ who is 1) the incarnate Truth; 2) the single head and cornerstone of the One Universal Church (his body).
Christianity as a theology (system of thinking about God).  A theology will try to be faithful to 1) how God sees Himself and 2) God's mission in the world.
Christianity as a church (visible body of Christians organized and governed in a certain way).  A church will try to be faithful to how Christ envisions the church to be LIVING through her members, which we can read in the New Testament.

Only Jesus knows 100% certain who belong to the One Universal Church, while we pilgrims on this earth who are still progressing can only know approximately:

some from unbelief to belief,
some from being a Christian to an apostate, while
some from a Christian belonging to "heretic" theology / church to one closer to The Truth

Why are there multiple Christian theologies and churches?  Answer: because there are multiple interpretations of the Bible and multiple ways tradition are being integrated into a church's life and a Christian's spirituality.
But there is only one Truthmaker God while we humans, who are swimming in a sea of truths, need to use a combination of personal discernment and consulting the collective judgments (the many churches) to decide to the best of our human ability what the truth about a matter IS, by using our intellect that is stamped with the ability to participate in God's Truth.  What's multiple is multiple approximations of the single Truth, where God (as Truthmaker) becomes our Truer, i.e. the nurturer and the shaper of our mind's purification (through our experiences in life) to better able to separate false claimants of truths about Him (hence the many warnings of false teacher and false prophets like Prosperity gospel teachers) from the orthodox truths.  As Christians, we strive to hear the voice of the True Shepherd and shape our lives accordingly; it's a lifelong pursuit but Jesus promised to lead us along the right path, echoing the promise God made to Israelites in the Psalms.
For a good philosophical discussion about how this works, I highly recommend the lectures from the 10th Annual Aquinas Philosophy Workshop on Knowledge, Truth, and Wisdom in Aquinas, recordings here.  The most pertinent lecture about how The Truthmaker helps us sort the truths we see in our experience is lecture 6 The Divine Ideas and the Truth in Things, handout here.
God came to establish a church.  Not any church, but the Eastern Orthodox church, the church of the first thousand years.
Yes, God came to establish ONE church in Jesus, the Universal Church who is the SINGLE body of Christ.  But how do we identify it?  It's too simple to say that "The church of the first thousand years is the Eastern Orthodox church" because if you read the history of Christianity in the first 400-500 years, you'll notice that there were many claimants who were deemed "heretic" already, so the choice was already made for you since the heretic churches mostly died out (although the ideas keep being resurrected in modern times in new heretic churches of the past centuries).
"heretic" literally means "those who walk another path", meaning that the "false church" hold teachings that guide their faithful to walk their faith in another path other than the path set as trustworthy by an orthodox church.  Historical examples: the Montanists, Arian churches, the Donatists, etc.  So at best, the Eastern Orthodox Church can claim to be THE "orthodox" visible church up to the East-West Schism.
The Protestant vision is that all visible churches are fallible, which means they should keep striving to reform themselves, ecclesia semper reformanda est.  But they don't have the same degree of deviation; some churches are more orthodox than others.  Evangelical Protestant Prof. Roger Olson helpfully uses the concept of "centered set" rather than a "bounded set" (read his article Who is A "Real Christian?" and others on the same topic).  The more a church is closer to how Jesus envisions it, the more it is a true church.
Any one church today can claim to be THE True church, but it's up to an individual believer to choose a church using their best judgment, aided by certain foundational principles that they firmly believe, such as sola scriptura.  For a good guide to intelligently, scholarly, and charitably navigate through the choices (from an evangelical Protestant angle) I highly recommend Gavin Ortlund's Truth Unites YouTube channel.  Several relevant episodes:

Is Private Judgment a Problem for Protestantism
The 5 Minute Case for Protestantism
Which Denomination Should You Choose?
How to KNOW You're in the Right Church
Are Catholics Christians?  Why Protestants Can Say YES
When Should You Leave Your Church?


The "centrist set" idea sounds similar to the prototype theory of categorisation, which I'm always keen to apply to new problems!

While I am Eastern Orthodox, I would never refer to it as the church of the first thousand years. It is The Church as far as I am concerned. Unless you are using the same symbolic 1000 = long period of time as the Bible does.

Ultimately, for us there is only 1 truth. Though I would tend to agree with people like Jordan Peterson that God is actually "more than Truth", but is the fundamental underlying foundation for truth itself.

the bible is true
in a very strange way
it's true in that
it provides the basis for
truth itself
and so it's like a meta truth without it
there couldn't even be the possibility
of
truth
and so maybe that's the most true thing
the most true thing isn't some truth per
se it's
that which provides the precondition for
all judgments of truth i can't see any
holes in that argument and i can't see
any holes in it from a scientific
perspective either because i think we do
know well enough now as scientists that
the problem of
deriving ethical direction from the
collection of facts is an intractable
problem there's too many facts there's
an infinite number of facts they do not
provide an unerring guide for action
they can't
there's too many of them they have to be
prioritized and as soon as they are
prioritized well then you're in the
ethical domain -Jordan Peterson "The Bible Is The Precondition For Truth"

There are multiple Churches in the modern era, most of these are directly because of sin. The hunger for power within the western church for example is one of the causes of the Great Schism and is also the primary cause of the Reformation by Luther (the greedy practice of selling forgiveness among other things). And then pile on top of that some major eisegesis and suddenly you have a few thousand denominations, sects, cults, spin off religions... (or some demonic visions to help them along)

From the Eastern Orthodox perspective, however, the biggest single reason for the Great Schism was the reassertion of Papal claims to have jurisdictional authority over all the Churches of Christendom. Ever since Bishop Victor of Rome near the end of the second century tried to dictate to the Quartodeciman Christians of Asia Minor concerning the dating of Pascha, a succession of strong Roman bishops, as we have seen, steadily promoted Papal claims over Churches beyond the Roman Church’s geographic territory, even though this was in violation of the original pattern of each bishop having jurisdictional authority over his own geographic territory—a pattern clearly affirmed in the canons of the first four Ecumenical Councils. Gradually the Papacy did manage to gain at least nominal authority over all the churches of Western Europe, as we have also seen, by the time of the powerful Pope Nicholas I in the middle of the 9th century. OCA website

This does not mean that the Holy Spirit cannot work through these other churches that all attempt to worship in their flawed understanding. Afterall much charity is performed by the protestants. But it would be better if they returned to the Church proper, bringing their unique forms of praise and charity to the Church.
And to be fair, Orthodox, Catholics, and any denomination that still understands heresy is a problem understand that the current state of things is wrong, that there should be only one church. And reunification is a goal, but due to doctrinal differences reunification is remaining at an impasse.

Reports suggest that Francis and Bartholomew have talked about staging some sort of “ecumenical synod” together in 2025, to mark the 1,700th anniversary of the Council of Nicea and its famous creed, which both churches share.


Bartholomew, however, despite being the traditional “first among equals” among Orthodox prelates, leads an extremely small flock — almost a “virtual church” — in Constantinople. The big dogs in the Orthodox world long have been the Russians and the Greeks, neither of whom generally shares Bartholomew’s rosy assessment of the state of things with Rome.
Moreover, the Russians are even less inclined than normal right now to follow Bartholomew’s lead, given the mutual recriminations over his decision to recognize the autocephaly, or independence, of the Orthodox church in Ukraine, which Moscow insists is its own.

(See here for more info on that...)

One of the best ways to look into things like which denomination is more correct we should look at the fruits of the church in question. (Charity, Giving, Safeguarding the faith, any miracles?, etc.) (Matthew 7:19-20)
Do they follow the traditions and teachings of the pre-schism church fathers and those of the ecumenical councils? (John 17:20–23 and Ephesians 4:3)
Do they respect the Bible as a part of the tradition of the church, understanding the teachings of the apostles and tradition preceded the scriptures?

692, the Council in Trullo was held in Constantinople, and is recognized by the Eastern Orthodox Church as a part of the 6th Ecumenical Council. Canon 2 of this council gives ecumenical authority to several local councils and Church Father writings that came before. The Orthodox biblical canon comes from this.

Are the teachings of the church in question aligned with the above things?

OP has a point though, the eastern orthodox church has been around for quite a while.

I think a glimpse into the New Testament Church, at least what is written about it in Scripture, shows an elevated view of the written word more than merely a part of church tradition.  Preach the word, Timothy, and not tradition. By the word encourage, correct, rebuke, and train unto righteousness.  Not tradition.  Tradition may be important but, in the New Testament,  it is never on a par with scripture.

@MikeBorden You can be of that opinion, though I will point out the Bible was maybe assembled in AD382+... while the first ecumenical council was in AD325. The Bible as we have it today was not required to stomp out major heresy nor stopped significant church fathers from teaching.

@Wyrsa But wasn't it "officially" assembled out of what was already accepted as Scripture?  The very early church fathers were already quoting it and opposing heresy by it long before it was made "official".  It ends up being a difference of whether the church produced the Bible or merely recognized it as such.

@MikeBorden I'm certain that the various apostles wrote more letters than are in the Bible. I'm mostly thinking of the early persecuted church, who would have likely had 1 gospel and maybe a few letters. Paul wrote a lot of the new testament epistles, I'm certain the other apostles wrote a lot as well. The Church canonized the scriptures after defeating the major arian heresy... the first 200ish years the church survived without a proper Bible or structure. This produced tradition, the Bible is part of the tradition, not sperate from it.

@Wyrsa "the first 200ish years the church survived without a proper Bible or structure.".  Do you mean except for the Old Testament (prior to 1 BC) and the New Testament (prior to 90 AD)?  Do you mean "without structure" except for (for example) the epistles to the Corinthians, the Ephesians, Timothy, and Titus, or even Acts?  These letters were copied, and copied, and circulated.  That is exactly why the manuscript evidence is overwhelming for the authenticity and accuracy of what we have.  Tradition, where it is valid, comes from Scripture and is defended thereby.

@Wyrsa The idea that the Church survived for a while bereft of authority and that this survival produced tradition, part of which is the Bible, is quite frightening.


OP:: I'm just curious how their can be more than one truth at the same time? [How can there be Christianities?]

We need some definitions before answering.

And when he [Barnabus] had found him [Saul/Paul], he brought him unto Antioch. And it came to pass, that a whole year they assembled themselves with the church, and taught much people. And the disciples were called Christians first in Antioch. Acts 11:26

Christian means "a follower of Christ" (see Strong's, Vines, Thayers).
Church means "a calling out of", a gathering.  Christ said I will build My church, My body, My gathering.
Lastly, in the very early church, the church was defined by its location.  For example, we can see the 7 churches of Revelation.  One was at Smyrna.  One was at Laodicea.  One was at Rome.  One was at Ephesus.
With these things in mind, we can begin to answer the question How can there be more than one truth at a time.
The problem is this is a redefinition of church from assembly to a truth place.  That idea simply doesn't exist in scripture.  On the other hand, if the truth per se is identified as Christ, like in a follower of Christ, we begin to get somewhere.
This is where creeds began.  I believe ...  The earliest was the Apostle's Creed.
Even while walking with apostles and having creeds, errors crept in very early.  Leaving the first love.  Holding to the doctrine of Balaam or Nicolaitans.  Allowing Jezebel into the church.  Pretending works to be alive.  Being lukewarm.

OP: God came to establish a church. Not any church. The church of the first thousand years is the eastern orthodox church.

The OP needs to explain this comment.  On its face, it means the second thousand years has no true church.
Is there more than one church?  Yes.  Is there more than one truth?  No.


how there can be more than one truth at the same time?

There can't.
There is only one truth.
But there are many untruths.
And many of those untruths present themselves as the true message of  God as recorded in the Bible.
Satan is the father of lies, not because he lies all the time, but because he tells the truth nearly all the time.
This is hardly surprising today, as the process of diverging Christianities was already beginning as soon as Jesus died.
Jesus and the apostles were well aware of it, recorded it, and warned people about it.
Here are just a few examples:

Matthew 24:4–5: And Jesus answered and said unto them, Take heed that no man deceive you.
For many shall come in my name, saying, I am Christ; and shall deceive many.
Matthew 7:15:
Beware of false prophets, which come to you in sheep's clothing, but inwardly they are ravening wolves.
Acts 20:29–30: For I know this, that after my departing shall grievous wolves enter in among you, not sparing the flock.
Also of your own selves shall men arise, speaking perverse things, to draw away disciples after them.
1 Timothy 5:15: For some are already turned aside after Satan.
2 Peter 2:1–2: But there were false prophets also among the people, even as there shall be false teachers among you, who privily shall bring in damnable heresies, even denying the Lord that bought them, and bring upon themselves swift destruction.
And many shall follow their pernicious ways; by reason of whom the way of truth shall be evil spoken of.
1 John 4:1: Beloved, believe not every spirit, but try the spirits whether they are of God: because many false prophets are gone out into the world.
2 Corinthians 11:3–4:
But I fear, lest by any means, as the serpent beguiled Eve through his subtilty, so your minds should be corrupted from the simplicity that is in Christ.
For if he that cometh preacheth another Jesus, whom we have not preached, or if ye receive another spirit, which ye have not received, or another gospel, which ye have not accepted, ye might well bear with him.
2 Corinthians 11:13–15:
For such are false apostles, deceitful workers, transforming themselves into the apostles of Christ.
And no marvel; for Satan himself is transformed into an angel of light.
Therefore it is no great thing if his ministers also be transformed as the ministers of righteousness; whose end shall be according to their works.

For any denomination, one must ask whether their doctrines are derived from the Bible, or the Bible is simply used to justify their doctrines?
Here, and more so on the Hermeneutics.SE site, these two ways of interpreting the meaning of the Bible correspond to exegesis (taking ideas from the text) and eisegesis (imposing one's ideas on the text).

Of course the fact that the various denominations interpret the Bible in different ways isn't the only reason there are so many different versions of Christianity.
If you look at my answer above, you'll see that my concluding lines actually included a specific doctrine, a doctrine presented as if everyone accepts that it is true. (And if you didn't notice it, then you now realize how easy it is do be deceived by a small lie wrapped in a big truth.)
I implied that the Bible is the only source of truth.
But that isn't a fact that is accepted by all denominations.
The Catholic Church for instance treats the Bible as one source of God's truth, but not the only one.
For them, additional truth can be provided by traditions handed down from the early Church Fathers, and by new inspiration through the Pope and Majesterium.
And the LDS Church has an entire Book of Mormon full of new revelations.
There is no single central authority on Earth that declares what the permissible sources of truth are or how those sources may be interpreted.
Instead we live in a world where there are many such authorities, each believing all the others to be wrong.

and by new revelations given directly to the Pope. https://www.vatican.va/content/catechism/en/part_one/section_one/chapter_two/artcile_2/iii_the_interpretation_of_the_heritage_of_faith.html  The magisterium (i.e the Pope in communion with the Bishops) doesn't go beyond what you correctly stated about traditions.   There have never been revelations given directly to the Pope that add to the deposit of faith.

@PeterTurner, I've reworded it, but if you can say it better, please do. One example I'm thinking of is the transfer of solemnity from the Sabbath to Sunday, something that the Church claims was done under its own authority and not by scriptural authority. See Who changed the Sabbath to Sunday according to the Seventh Day Adventists? - Christianity Stack Exchange
